# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x^2\left(\arctan(x)-\frac \pi2\right)+x$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I'm new to calculus and limits (I'm doing IB Math AA HL). How would I find the limit for this trigonometric function as $x$ approaches infinity? Is there an algebraic way or a way to solve it graphically?

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2\left(\arctan(x)-\frac \pi2\right)+x$$

I tried just plugging in values but realised it would take too long that way and also this is a non-GDC problem which means I'm not allowed any technology while trying to solve this.

Comment: This is a very difficult limit for someone relatively new to the subject, and quite frankly the simplest solution probably requires the use of Taylor series. Any reason you were thrown off into the deep end of the pool for this? What are the tricks you have in your toolbox so far for solving limits?

Comment: Hi @NinadMunshi, my tutor likes to take a brute force approach clearly haha. I'm not familiar with the Taylor series. My 'tricks' involve graphing and just hard and fast approaches of substitution but I quickly realised they're not efficient, especially for questions like these.

Comment: I see, I'll take it up with my tutor then. Maybe he can teach me the Taylor series. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewriting the limmand, we have

$$x^2\left(\arctan x -\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + x = x - x^2\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

by the arctangent identity $\arctan x + \arctan \frac{1}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x>0$. Using the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$ the limit becomes

$$\lim_{t\to0^+} \frac{1}{t} - \frac{\arctan t}{t^2} = \lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t-\arctan t}{t^2}$$

Then by L'Hopital

$$= \lim_{t\to0^+} \frac{1-\frac{1}{1+t^2}}{2t} = \lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t}{2(1+t^2)} = 0$$

Comment: Thank you, I'll also have a look with my extra help to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} x^2\left(\tan^{-1} x-\frac \pi2\right)+x$$
Using the identity $\tan^{-1} x+\tan^{-1} (1/x)=\pi/2$ and the fact that $\tan^{-1} u\sim u-u^3/3$ when $u\to 0$ you have:
$$ x^2\left(\tan^{-1} x-\frac \pi2\right)+x=x-x^2 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\sim x-x^2\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3x^3}\right)=\frac{1}{3x}\to0 
$$